# How to find matching records comparing one field in a table to several fields in another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Access 2010, I have two tables where I want to find the matching records in one of them by comparing similar fields (1:1 and 1:M).

Table 1, [760Vadim] has four fields: Folio, PID Number1, PID Number2, PID Number3

Table 2, [no_dupes] has two fields: Folio, PID

I need to find all records in [760Vadim] that have a matching value from the similar fields in [no_dupes].

Comparing Folio fields is a 1:1 join whereas comparing the PIDs is 1:M (1:3) and they both need to be compared at the same time!

I have tried this using a Join and the following SQL statements:

1.) Works, but only for one field at a time!

```
SELECT [760Vadim].*, no_dupes.PID
FROM no_dupes INNER JOIN 760Vadim ON no_dupes.PID = [760Vadim].[PID Number1]
WHERE (((no_dupes.PID) Like [760Vadim].[PID Number1]));
```

2.) Does not work when comparing PID to two fields, 0 records returned...!

```
SELECT [760Vadim].*, no_dupes.PID
FROM no_dupes INNER JOIN 760Vadim ON (no_dupes.PID = [760Vadim].[PID Number2]) AND (no_dupes.PID = [760Vadim].[PID Number1])
WHERE (((no_dupes.PID) Like [760Vadim].[PID Number1])) OR (((no_dupes.PID) Like [760Vadim].[PID Number2]));
```

3.) This kind of works... but returns duplicates... and going back into design view, it says invalid operator due to changing AND to OR, so it doesn't like my = sign?

```
SELECT [760Vadim].*, no_dupes.PID
FROM no_dupes INNER JOIN 760Vadim ON (no_dupes.PID = [760Vadim].[PID Number2]) OR (no_dupes.PID = [760Vadim].[PID Number1])
WHERE (((no_dupes.PID) Like [760Vadim].[PID Number1])) OR (((no_dupes.PID) Like [760Vadim].[PID Number2]));
```

Also tried [another forums](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=91488) suggestions:
1.) Works (i think...), but duplicates again!

```
SELECT [760Vadim].*
FROM 760Vadim, no_dupes
WHERE ((([760Vadim].folio)=[no_dupes].[DATA_SO1])) OR ((([760Vadim].[PID Number1])=[no_dupes].[PID])) OR ((([760Vadim].[PID Number2])=[no_dupes].[PID])) OR ((([760Vadim].[PID Number3])=[no_dupes].[PID]));
```

It seems to go through and return a record if a match is found for folio, AND returns another record (could be a duplicate) if a matching PID is found from the three other fields.

From [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512491/how-to-select-2-fields-from-one-table-and-compare-it-on-1-field-of-the-another-ta) it is suggested to use the CONCAT feature inside of the Join to remove the duplicates.

I also tried adding: `GROUP BY [760Vadim].*;` after the where statement to remove duplicates but no avail, it says cannot group ALL records, which is what I need. I am new to Access but have some familiarity with SQL ([basics](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)).

Apologies if posted in wrong stack, it may sit better in Programmers or Database stackexchange?

**EDIT:**
I tried the option without the Join as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.*
FROM   [760Vadim] v 
WHERE
      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  no_dupes nd 
         WHERE nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number1] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number2] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number3]
             OR nd.folio LIKE v.[folio] )
```

The option you provided only returns the four columns from the 760Vadim table, it's preferred to see ALL of them.
I also noticed it didn't compare the folio fields (that specification is lost in my ramble, sorry).

Did I format it correctly to `SELECT DISTINCT` all columns in 760Vadim IF a match is found in no_dupes?

When I go back into SQL/design view, it throws an exception error and changes the SQL to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.* INTO query_final
FROM 760Vadim AS v
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT * FROM  no_dupes nd 
         WHERE nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number1] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number2] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number3]
             OR nd.folio LIKE v.[folio] ))<>False));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options

**Using DISTINCT/JOIN**

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.folio, 
                v.[PID Number1], 
                v.[PID Number2], 
                v.[PID Number3] 
FROM   [760Vadim] v 
       INNER JOIN no_dupes nd 
         ON nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number1] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number2] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number3]
```

**USING DISTINCT/EXISTS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       v.folio, 
       v.[PID Number1], 
       v.[PID Number2], 
       v.[PID Number3] 
FROM   [760Vadim] v 
WHERE
      EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  no_dupes nd 
         WHERE nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number1] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number2] 
             OR nd.pid LIKE v.[PID Number3] )
```

Comment: i've edited my original question with a response, thanks for the pointers so far. They are definitely leading my in the right direction!